# error mouting a container volume in docker

Tags: docker, docker-run

I'm new to docker and following through their getting started tutorial in the docs. I'm currently at the part where I need to mount a volume in order to persist data between container reruns. But when I try running the command `docker run -dp 3000:3000 --mount type=volume,src=todo-db,target=/etc/todos getting-started`, I get an error response:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'D:/Program Files/Git/etc/todos' mount path must be absolute.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

From what I understand, I think the problem comes from the `target` parameter for the `--mount` flag. The path should be the target path **in the container**, correct? But for some reason i think it's reading **my** machine's path of `D:/Program Files/Git/etc/todos`. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is it a Windows or a Linux container you run?

Comment: @HansKilian it's a linux container. Btw, the problem was due to using Git Bash. Apparently Git Bash changes the path.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for an answer for this particular error, the culprit is Git Bash as specified [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6754#issuecomment-629702199). I tried using Powershell and it worked like a charm.